# Yii criteria issue with selecting values from foreign tables

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, criteria

**Hi i want to select following underlined values from table.i tried but its not working....**
[image]

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;       

    $criteria->select = array('description', 'id','rate','item_unit_id');
    $criteria->with=array("item_unit","color");
    $criteria->together = true; 
    $criteria->addSearchCondition("description", $_GET['query']);

    $criteria->limit = $this->limit;

    $items = Item::model()->findAll($criteria);
    $suggestions = array();
    $x=0;
    foreach ($items as $c) {
        $suggestions[$x]['value'] = $c->description;
        $suggestions[$x]['id'] = $c->id;
        $suggestions[$x]['rate'] = $c->rate;
        $suggestions[$x]['unit'] = $c->item_unit->name;
        $x++;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you would've read the documentation you would know, but because you didn't, you don't :)

However, this might help you:

```
$criteria->select = 't.id, t.description, t.rate, t.code, color.name, item_unit.name';
$criteria->with = array(
    "item_unit" => array(
        'together' => true,
        'joinType' => 'INNER JOIN'
    ),
    "color" => array(
        'together' => true,
        'joinType' => 'INNER JOIN',
    )
); 

$criteria->addSearchCondition("t.description", $_GET['query']);
$criteria->limit = $this->limit;

$items = Item::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: bro it gives this error... Relation "item_unit" is not defined in active record class "Item".

Comment: well, define the relation, isn't this obvious? Or better, start reading Yii user guide, you are not ready to use Yii.

Comment: thanks friend it should be 'itemUnit' not 'item_unit'...now works fine :)

Comment: I have one question...why use INNER JOIN in this...without it also works

Comment: Because the default is `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and if you know the difference between the two, you know why you need a `INNER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT/RIGHT` join, basically this makes sure you get records back only if they exists in all the joined tables.